# Sync Google Code and GitHub

Tags: git, github, google-code

I have a Git repository on GitHub that has already been established. Now, I want to mirror that same repository onto Google Code. Either that, or I want Google Code's Source tab to either disappear or point to GitHub. Since that doesn't seem possible, how do I sync the two repositories? All the other answers don't cover if the first Git repo is already established.

Comment: This seems like you're more concerned about the UI than actually storing the code in 2 places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you already set up a remote for Github named *origin* (as you will if you followed Github's instructions), you can add a second URL to it for Google Code:

```
git remote set-url --add origin https://project.googlecode.com/git
```

Now you'll automatically push to both Github and Google Code at once when you `git push` to that remote. That's probably the easiest way to keep them synced.

Comment: Do you have to do that for each "clone"?

Comment: this works, but how do you configure different credentials for each repo?

Answer (score 1):

Simply clone the git repository from one location, Google code or github. Then add a remote to the other repo

```
git remote add google git://...google code clone url
```

then simply use `git push google` and `git push origin`